# Find the value of $\frac\Delta\nabla-\frac\nabla\Delta$

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

If $\Delta$ and $\nabla$ represent forward and backward difference operator then find the value of
$$\frac\Delta\nabla-\frac\nabla\Delta$$
I know that $\Delta f(x)=f(x+h)-f(x)$ and $\nabla f(x)=f(x)-f(x-h)$.

But what will be $\frac\Delta\nabla f(x)=\frac1\nabla\{f(x+h)-f(x)\}$?

Will someone please help?

Comment: I assume you substitute the definitions you gave into those triangles.

Comment: @Michael;Yes what will be $\dfrac{1}{\triangledown}f(x)$

Comment: Is there a difficulty substituting the down-point triangle in the denominator?

Comment: I also suspect your notation is not the best.  I am guessing you literally substitute "$f(x+h)-f(x)$" for up-triangle and "$f(x)-f(x-h)$" for down triangle, with the understanding that this is all in terms of some function $f$, without trying to define a new operator for a ratio acting on a function. So likely you are really trying to compute $$\frac{\Delta f}{\nabla f}-\frac{\nabla f}{\Delta f}$$ Note that, in general, math notation should make things easier, not harder.  If the confusion is only about notation then the notation is bad.

Comment: @Michael;Yes you are right and this is what the question says and asks